# Implementing SSL between JAVA GUI & C++ Server

Tags: java, c, ssl, client-server, communication

I have an GUI which is designed in JAVA and act as an client, and can communicate remotely to an server which is written in C/C++.  Communication between them is made through Sockets. However the messages sent are not encrypted and is vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks. I was wondering what the best solution will be to protect the communication and wanted to implement SSL. Is it possible to do so, and if yes, what toolkit I should look into.

Comment: [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) !

Comment: @MM: He's talking about a Java client, OpenSSL would be of no use in this case!

Comment: @GyroGearless: OpenSSL is a toolkit which has many features such as encrypt/decrypt. How it can not help? Just encrypt in one side and decrypt in the other side.

Comment: @MM: OpenSSL is a fine toolkit, but i'm not aware that there is an easy way (JNI Binding?) to integrate it inside an Java application. And there is perhaps no need for this, as Java has SSL "built in"

Comment: @GyroGearless: Remember another side is C/C++, I suggested a single solution for both side.

Comment: @MM. Java contains an SSL implementation called JSSE. That's all he needs. He doesn't need an external SSL library of any kind, especially one to which you can't produce a Java interface. The fact that the peer is C/C++ is completely irrelevant given that RFC 2246 exists.

Answer (score 0):

Java contains an SSL implementation called JSSE. See the Javadoc for the javax.net.ssl package. There is also a tutorial, and several examples are provided with the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

You might not even need to modify the server at all. You could just stick [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/index.html) in front of it.

A warning: With TLS/SSL you face a whole bunch of additional error conditions that you might need report or log, especially concerning certificates (wrong, expired, unable to verify due to networking / DNS issues)

Comment: Implement JSSE on the client side. On the server you bind your C++ app to a local port on 127.0.0.1 only. Bind stunnel to the public network interface, it decrypts the incoming SSL and forwards it to the unmodified but otherwise unreachable C++ server app.